# Unmounted/mounted drives in dock 18.04

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock

So  upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, how do I get my passwd protected drives to show in dock/launcher?

It is very frustrating to use nautilus->other locations and then mount+passwd, then you have to close and reopen nautilus to do next drive.. very time consuming.

Comment: It seems that you're asking how to access password protected drives, from your dock, without entering a password? Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: No I wish to have all locked,unmounted,mounted drives to be there like old ubuntus.